# React-Router-Dom unable to render page but routes back due to PrivateRoute

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am having some issues with my routing currently when authenticated. Whenever I try to access my ViewPortfolio page at localhost:3000/portfolio/***portfolioId*** it will redirect me back to my homepage. I am not sure what is going on. I have also tried manipulating the URL by modifying it to the correct URL link but it also redirects me back to `/homepage` when I am authenticated. The source codes can be found below. App.js is my router with PrivateRoute as the private route component and finally, CreateInterview.js where I redirect using js `windows.location` function to ViewPortfolio.js which will use `useParams()` react hook to get the param. But instead now after creating successfully and redirect to the correct URL with the portfolioId it will redirect back to homepage within less than a second.

PrivateRoute.js

```
import React from 'react' 
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom' 
import { useAuth } from '../contexts/AuthContext' 
 
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => { 
  const { currentUser } = useAuth() 
 
  return ( 
    <Route 
      {...rest} 
      render={(props) => { 
        if (currentUser) { 
          return <Component {...props} /> 
        } else { 
          return <Redirect to={{ 
            pathname: "/", 
            state:{ 
              from: props.location 
            } 
          }}/> 
        } 
      } 
      }> 
 
    </Route> 
  ) 
} 
 
export default PrivateRoute
```

App.js

```
import React from "react" 
.
.
.
import PublicRoute from "./PublicRoute"; 
 
function App() { 
    return ( 
        <AuthProvider> 
            <Router> 
                <Switch> 
                    {/* Auth Routes */} 
                    <PublicRoute exact path='/' component={Login} /> 
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    <PrivateRoute exact path='/createInterview' component={CreateInterview} /> 
                    <PrivateRoute path='/manageInterview' component={ManageInterview} /> 
                    <PrivateRoute path='/portfolio/:portfolioId' component={ViewPortfolio} /> 
 
                    {/* Non-Existance Routes */} 
                    <Route path="*" component={() => "404 NOT FOUND"} /> 
                </Switch> 
            </Router> 
        </AuthProvider> 
    ) 
} 
 
export default App
```

CreatInterview.js redirecting in js (onSubmit of the form)

```
async function handleSubmit(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    setError(''); 
    setLoading(true); 
 
    await database.portfolioRef.add({ 
      intervieweeName: intervieweeNameRef.current.value, 
      intervieweeEmail: intervieweeEmailRef.current.value, 
      intervieweeMobileNumber: intervieweeMobileRef.current.value, 
      projectTitle: projectTitleRef.current.value, 
      portfolioTitle: portfolioNameRef.current.value, 
      dateCreated: new Date().toLocaleString('en-SG'), 
      createdBy: currentUser.displayName 
    }).then(function(docRef) { 
      console.log("This is the Document ID " + docRef.id.toString()); 
      console.log(docRef.id); 
      window.location = '/portfolio/' + docRef.id; 
    }) 
 
    setLoading(false) 
  }
```

Part of ViewPortfolio.js to receive the `portfolioId` from CreateInterview.js

```
const ViewPortfolio = () => { 
    let { portfolioId } = useParams();
```

AuthContext.js

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react" 
import { auth, database } from "../firebase"; 
import { getDocs, query, where } from "firebase/firestore"; 
 
const AuthContext = React.createContext() 
 
export function useAuth() { 
    return useContext(AuthContext) 
} 
 
export function AuthProvider({ children }) { 
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null) 
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true) 
 
    function login(email, password) { 
        return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(() => { 
            const Doc = query(database.usersRef, where("email", "==", email)); 
 
            getDocs(Doc).then((querySnapshot) => { 
                let values = ''; 
 
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => { 
                    values = doc.id; 
                }); 
 
                var userUpdate = database.usersRef.doc(values); 
                userUpdate.update({ 
                    lastActive: new Date().toLocaleString('en-SG'), 
                }) 
            }) 
        }); 
    } 
 
    function logout() { 
        return auth.signOut(); 
    } 
 
    function forgetPassword(email) { 
        return auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email); 
    } 
 
    function updateEmail(email) { 
        return currentUser.updateEmail(email) 
    } 
 
    function updatePassword(password) { 
        return currentUser.updatePassword(password) 
    } 
 
    function updateDisplayName(name) { 
        return currentUser.updateDisplayName(name) 
    } 
 
    useEffect(() => { 
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged( user => { 
            setLoading(false) 
            setCurrentUser(user) 
        }) 
 
        return unsubscribe 
    }, []) 
 
    const value = { 
        currentUser, 
        login, 
        forgetPassword, 
        logout, 
        updateEmail, 
        updatePassword, 
        updateDisplayName, 
    } 
 
    return ( 
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}> 
            {!loading && children} 
        </AuthContext.Provider> 
    ) 
}
```

Comment: Can you also share the `AuthContext` and how it's providing a context value?

Comment: Instead of using window.location try useHistory() hook

Comment: @Abid1174 useHistory() hook to post the state with the param and useLocation() to retrieve the state? However, currently I have no issue with the passing of the param but maintaining the rendering of the portfolio page. Cause I am redirected within a split second of successfully being redirect to the correct page.

Comment: window.location will make a re-load of the page. so your app state may be cleared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial `currentUser` state matches the unauthenticated state, so when the app initially renders, if you are accessing a protected route the redirection will occur because the `currentUser` state hasn't updated yet.

Since `onAuthStateChanged` returns `null` for unauthenticated users then I suggest using anything *other than* `null` for the initial `currentUser` state. `undefined` is a good indeterminant value. You can use this indeterminant value to conditionally render a loading indicator, or nothing at all, while the auth status is confirmed on the initial render.

AuthProvider

```
export function AuthProvider({ children }) { 
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(); // <-- undefined
  ...
```

PrivateRoute

```
const PrivateRoute = (props) => { 
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();

  if (currentUser === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading spinner, etc...
  }

  return currentUser
    ? (
      <Route {...props} />
    )
    : (
      <Redirect
        to={{ 
          pathname: "/", 
          state: { 
            from: props.location 
          } 
        }}
      />
    );
}
```

You should also really replace the `window.location = '/portfolio/' + docRef.id;` logic with a `history.push('/portfolio/' + docRef.id);` so you are not unnecessarily reloading the page.

```
const history = useHistory();

...

async function handleSubmit(e) { 
  e.preventDefault(); 
  setError(''); 
  setLoading(true); 

  try {
    const docRef = await database.portfolioRef.add({ 
      intervieweeName: intervieweeNameRef.current.value, 
      intervieweeEmail: intervieweeEmailRef.current.value, 
      intervieweeMobileNumber: intervieweeMobileRef.current.value, 
      projectTitle: projectTitleRef.current.value, 
      portfolioTitle: portfolioNameRef.current.value, 
      dateCreated: new Date().toLocaleString('en-SG'), 
      createdBy: currentUser.displayName 
    });
     
    history.push('/portfolio/' + docRef.id);
  } catch (error) {
    // handle error, clear loading state
    setLoading(false);
  }
}
```