# Login with Firebase and React Router Dom (How to use onAuthStateChanged)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, react-router-dom

I am a beginner in react and I have a problem here. I try to make website that have login page. I use firebase for authenticate my website. The problem is, how to implement `onAuthStateChange` to `react-router`. BTW I used Redux.

This is my App.js file:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {
  createUserDocumentFromAuth,
  onAuthStateChangedListener,
} from './utils/firebase/Firebase.utils';

import { setCurrentUser } from './store/action';

import './App.scss';

import Page from './routes/Page';
import Authentication from './routes/Authentication';

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const currentUser = useSelector(state => state.currentUser);

  const ProtectedRoutes = ({children }) => {
    if (!currentUser) {
      return <Navigate to="auth" replace />
    }
    return children
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChangedListener(user => {
      if (user) {
        createUserDocumentFromAuth(user);
      }
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(user));
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        index
        element={
          <ProtectedRoutes>
            <Page />
          </ProtectedRoutes>
        }
      />
      <Route path="auth" element={<Authentication />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I've investigated, what the problem is. I did console what the `currentUser` is, in first render it returns null, and after that it returns something. I think my `ProtectedRoutes` is correct, but now how to get the last state from current user. Or any alternative ways to solve this? BTW, this is my firebase.utils file:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import {
  getAuth,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  signInWithPopup,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
  onAuthStateChanged,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import {
  getFirestore,
  doc,
  getDoc,
  setDoc,
  collection,
  writeBatch,
  query,
  getDocs,
} from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "......",
  authDomain: "......",
  projectId: "......",
  storageBucket: "......",
  messagingSenderId: "......",
  appId: "......"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

provider.setCustomParameters({
  propmt: 'select_account',
});

export const auth = getAuth();
export const signInWithGooglePopup = () => signInWithPopup(auth, provider);

export const db = getFirestore();

export const addCollectionAndDocuments = async (collectionKey, objectsToAdd) => {
  const collectionRef = collection(db, collectionKey);
  const batch = writeBatch(db);

  objectsToAdd.forEach((object) => {
    const docRef = doc(collectionRef, object.title.toLowerCase())
    batch.set(docRef, object)

  })

  await batch.commit()
}

export const getCategoriesAndDocuments = async () => {
  const collectionRef = collection(db, 'categories')
  const q = query(collectionRef);

  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)
  const categoryMap = querySnapshot.docs.reduce((acc, docSnapshot) => {
    const { title, items } = docSnapshot.data()
    acc[title.toLowerCase()] = items;
    return acc
  }, {})

  return categoryMap
}

export const createUserDocumentFromAuth = async (
  userAuth,
  additionalInformation = {}
) => {
  if (!userAuth) return;

  const userDocRef = doc(db, 'users', userAuth.uid);
  const userSnapshot = await getDoc(userDocRef);

  if (!userSnapshot.exists()) {
    const { displayName, email } = userAuth;
    const createdAt = new Date();

    try {
      await setDoc(userDocRef, {
        email,
        displayName,
        createdAt,
        ...additionalInformation,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error creating the user.', error.message);
    }
  }

  return userDocRef;
};

export const createUserAuthWithEmailAndPassword = async (email, password) => {
  if (!email || !password) return;

  return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
};

export const signInUserAuthWithEmailAndPassword = async (email, password) => {
  if (!email || !password) return;

  return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
};

export const signOutUser = async () => await signOut(auth);

export const onAuthStateChangedListener = callback =>
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, callback);
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for help with. What exactly is the issue you are trying to resolve? Also, FYI the `ProtectedRoutes` component should be declared outside any other React component. Right now it's redeclared each render cycle which will unnecessarily unmount/remount all the children it's rendered.

Comment: What i excpected is, i just want to make login logic, so when the currentUser is true so we can redirect into "/" path

Comment: When `ProtectedRoutes` is declared it should have the current value of `currentUser` selected from redux. Are you just having issues reading this state and rendering the `Navigate` component or `children` prop?

Comment: Yes exactly sir, the currentUser have state null in first render and something in next render, and i just can get the state that is first render

Comment: I don't understand what you think the issue is. The initial `currentUser` state appears to be `null`, so that's what I'd expect to see on the initial render before any effects are run to fetch the user data, i.e. prior to `onAuthStateChanged` being called the first time. Is the issue rather that an already authenticated user is being redirected to log in on a page reload or something because (a) the app state isn't persisted and/or (b) the initial render cycle doesn't have a verified authentication status yet so the route protector assumes they are unauthenticated and redirects?

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71704109/8690857