# Is it normal to see other pages while refreshing the page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a React project with many routes - login and signup that leads to a dashboard. While in the dashboard after I'm logged in, if I refresh the page, I can see the login screen for a few seconds. It's just for a second, but still perceptible.

I was wondering if this is normal, and if not, what should I do to prevent it?

My routes code below:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
  <Route exact path='/login' element={<Index/>}/>
  <Route exact path='/cadastro' element={<Cadastro/>}/>
  <Route exact path="/" element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
  <Route exact  path='/*' element={<Dashboard/>}/>
  </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

edit - Google login auth:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthGoogleContext } from "../context/authGoogle";

export const PrivateRoutes = () => {
const { signed } = useContext(AuthGoogleContext);

return signed ?  <Outlet /> :   <Navigate to="/login" /> ;
};
```

google context:

```
     const [user, setUser] = useState(null);


  const auth = getAuth(app);
  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadStorageData = () => {
      const storageUser = sessionStorage.getItem("@Auth:user");
      const storageToken = sessionStorage.getItem("@Auth:token");
      if (storageToken && storageUser) {
        setUser(storageUser);
      }
    };
    loadStorageData();
  });

  const signGoogle = () => {
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    .then((result) => {
      const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
      const token = credential.accessToken;
      const user = result.user;
      setUser(user);
      sessionStorage.setItem("@Auth:token", token);
      sessionStorage.setItem("@Auth:user", JSON.stringify(user));
      }).catch((error) => {
      const errorCode = error.code;
      // const errorMessage = error.message;
      // const email = error.customData.email;
      // const credential = 
     GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
      console.log(errorCode);
     });
     }

  function signOut() {
    sessionStorage.clear();
    setUser(null);
  }

    return (
    <AuthGoogleContext.Provider value={{signGoogle, signed: !!user, user, 
    signOut}}>
        { children }
    </AuthGoogleContext.Provider>
```

Comment: Add some loading state to render some loading indicator while the authentication status is being set/confirmed/validated. Using some sort of state persistence often also helps here as you can initialize your authentication state to the last known status. Can you share a more complete and comprehensive code example for how you are handling your authentication and checks?

Comment: Yes, so far i only have a google login auth, so i will edit the post and put it there.  If you can, could you please provide some details of where can i put this loading state?

Comment: Does something like this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71704109/8690857 The answer is using RRDv5 APIs but the underlying issue and concept is nearly identical.

Comment: it actually solved my problem very well! no more login page on refresh, thanks.

Comment: Great, glad to hear you've resolved the issue. Cheers and good luck!