# Firebase auth and React protected route - just keeps redirecting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm not sure where the error in my logic is? Apologies in advance for nooby question, am new to React and Firebase. 
I have a sign-in page followed by a profile page to be protected. My logic in the PrivateRoute is that: If the user is authenticated, the `authorised` will be set to true and so the user will be directed to the profile page. And otherwise, the user will be directed back to the SignIn page.
My issue is that even when the user is signed in successfully, the user is unable to go to /profile and keeps getting redirected to /sign-in. Why is that?

**Code for Protected route:**

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const PrivateRoute = () => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    const [authorised, setAuthorised] = useState(false);
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        if (user) {
            setAuthorised(true);
        }
        if (!user) {
            setAuthorised(false);
        }
    });
    return(
        authorised ? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to="/sign-in"/>
    )
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

**Code for App.js**

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Profile from "./pages/Profile"

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Route path="/sign-in" element={<SignIn />} />

      <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}> 
        <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
      </Route>
  );
}
```

Appreciate any help, and thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because `authorised` is false on mount, so it redirects to `sign-in`. In your code, PrivateRoute is working with `profile` and not working with `sign-in`. It means after redirects to `sign-in`, you can't go back to `profile` even user has been signed in.

Please refer [React-Router-Dom unable to render page but routes back due to PrivateRoute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71703922/react-router-dom-unable-to-render-page-but-routes-back-due-to-privateroute) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Because onAuthStateChanged is asynchronous, your useState may be checking before receiving any information from Firebase. I suggest you use react-firebase-hooks and take advantage of the useAuthState function.

```
const PrivateRoute = () => {
const auth = getAuth();
const [user, loading] = useAuthState(auth);

if (loading) {
    return "Loading"
}
return user ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/sign-in" />
```

}